# Excel: Dividing comma separated single cell numbers

Tags: excel

I have a string of numbers in a single Excel cell separated by commas, e.g. `A2 = "4,3,2,7"`.  I want a formula to be able to divide those number by 2 in cell `B2`, e.g. `B2 = "2,1,1,3"` (odd numbers should round down rather than up)

The formula needs to be able to account for:
- smaller or larger string of numbers
- for both single and double digit numbers
- numbers that are even or odd
- no VBA
- formula can use multiple columns but not the delimited text to columns feature (due to cell location)

I was able to get a formula to sum the string of numbers in `A2` `(4,3,2,7 = 16)` but not able to divide by 2.  My formula to sum the string is below.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
{=SUM(IF(ISERR(VALUE(MID(A2,ROW($A$1:OFFSET($A$1,LEN(A2)-1,0‌​)),1))),0,VALUE(MID(‌​A2,ROW($A$1:OFFSET($‌​A$1,LEN(A2)-1,0)),1)‌​)))}
```

Comment: is there always 4 elements? I don't think it's doable for variable number of arguments without VBA

Comment: This website is not such as "tell me code". First, attempt yourself, if you get stuck, write your formula/code, then ask help.

Comment: You should write what you have tried so far and better specify your goal and problem.

Comment: Question updated above with my formula

Comment: After some explorations, I decided that it is not possible to do it with single cell formula. You have two ways: using more columns to parse them or using VBA to create custom formula.

Comment: Ok good to know, thanks. Do you have an example on using multiple columns w/o the delimited option?  I edited my question to include the option for multiple columns.

Comment: I think I did it with single cell formula :)

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, This is my second attempt to solve(I hope) your problem. If your string is in cell `A2`, then put this code inot cell `B2`:

```
=LEFT(IFERROR(ROUNDDOWN(MID(A2,1,1)/2,0),"")&","&IFERROR(ROUNDDOWN(MID(A2,3,1)/2,0),"")&","&IFERROR(ROUNDDOWN(MID(A2,5,1)/2,0),"")&","&IFERROR(ROUNDDOWN(MID(A2,7,1)/2,0),"")&","&IFERROR(ROUNDDOWN(MID(A2,9,1)/2,0),"")&","&IFERROR(ROUNDDOWN(MID(A2,11,1)/2,0),"")&","&IFERROR(ROUNDDOWN(MID(A2,13,1)/2,0),"")&","&IFERROR(ROUNDDOWN(MID(A2,15,1)/2,0),""),LEN(A2))
```

It can be worked with up to 8 number string, as well as odd numbers.

**Update**

This formula can handle double digit numbers but it supports only from 1 to 4 string numbers(e.g. (25,5,36,48)):

```
=LEFT(IFERROR(ROUNDDOWN(MID(A2,1,IFERROR(SEARCH(",",A2,1)-1,LEN(A2)))/2,0),"")&","&IFERROR(ROUNDDOWN(MID(A2,SEARCH(",",A2,1)+1,IFERROR(SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,1)+1)-SEARCH(",",A2,1)-1,LEN(A2)-SEARCH(",",A2,1)))/2,0),"")&","&IFERROR(ROUNDDOWN(MID(A2,SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,1)+1)+1,IFERROR(SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,1)+1)+1)-SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,1)+1)-1,LEN(A2)-SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,1))))/2,0),"")&","&IFERROR(ROUNDDOWN(MID(A2,SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,1)+1)+1)+1,IFERROR(SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,1)+1)+1)+1)-SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,1)+1)+1)-1,LEN(A2)-SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,1)+1)+1)))/2,0),""),LEN(A2))
```

Comment: That works perfect for single digit numbers, thank you!  Is it possible to adjust for both single and double digits?  Triple digits or greater do not need to be considered.

Comment: Ha, sounds good.  I'll work on expanding the formula to support a larger string.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

In your example, use this formula into cell `B1`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","000")/2,"000",",")
```

Then result will be like this:

```
 |    A    |    B    |
 +---------+---------+  
1| 4,2,6,8 | 2,1,3,4 |
2|
```

Comment: A mark for ingenuity - I don't think a more general solution is do-able except possibly in Excel 2016 with TEXTJOIN

Comment: I second Tom's +1 for the creativity.

Comment: bzimor - The substitute formula seems to work for even numbers but not odd or when the string is longer

Comment: Tom - I have 2016 Excel and will attempt a text join but that appears to function as concatenate. I suppose I may have to split the data into individual cells then rejoin into a single cell

Comment: Brad, you said "I want a single cell formula ". Also, you didn't write any criteria for numbers

Comment: The formula needs to be able to account for a smaller or larger string of numbers, even or odd.

Comment: No, it is not fair, if you just need a formula. edit your question, how you did, why you did and what you couldn't do. Nobody tries unless you explain briefly your problems.